# how do I do an sql swap of dates

Tags: sql, date, swap

how do I do an sql swap of dates between a set of dates and change to one specific date this is what i have:

{F_PM_SCHEDULES.PM_NEXT_DATE} in DateTime (2015, 01, 02, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2015, 01, 31, 23, 59, 00) and
{F_EQUIP_TYPES.FC_RC_CODE} = "CE"

I would like to do a SQL swap any and all dates in between 1/2/2015 - 1/31/2015 to 1/1/2015

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with _sql swap_? It's not all cleat to me.

Comment: I would like to use an sql command to swap the dates between 1/2/2015 - 1/31/2015 and change them all to 1/1/2015

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change all dates in the range 1/2/2015 - 1/31/2015 to 1/1/2015 in some column this update query should be what you want:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourDateField = '1/1/2015'
WHERE YourDateField BETWEEN '1/2/2015' AND '1/31/2015'
```

With reservation for the correct date format for your specific language.

If I misunderstood your intent please let me know.